# Dedekind Cuts: Addition Axioms

Tags: real-analysis

In Step 4 of his exegesis of Dedekind cuts, Rudin proves that the axioms for addition hold in R, with 0* playing the role of 0. While proving the 5th axiom (To every x $\in$ F corresponds an element -x $\in$ F such that x+(-x)=0), Rudin states the following:

Fix $\alpha$ $\in$ R. Let $\beta$ be the set of all p with the following property: There exists r>0 such that -p-r $\notin$ $\alpha$. In other words, some rational number smaller than -p fails to be in $\alpha$. We show that $\beta$ $\in$ R and that $\alpha$ + $\beta=0*$

Why does this not violate property #2 of a cut? Property #2 states: If p $\in$ $\alpha$, q$\in$ Q and $q<p$, then q$\in$$\alpha$. How is it possible to have some rational number smaller than -p that fails to be in $\alpha$?

Maybe one reason is that p was negative to begin with, such that $-p>p$, for example, if $p=-\sqrt2$, then $-p$ would clearly not be contained in the cut containing $p=-\sqrt2$. But if this is the case, why not specify this outright?

Comment: I don't get your question. Which cut presumably violates property #2?

Comment: This is the line that was troublesome for me: "In other words, some rational number smaller than -p fails to be in α."

Comment: Well, that's what the condition means. Since $r$ is positive, $-p-r$ is smaller than $-p$.

Comment: Consider a simple case: the Ded Cut $\alpha$ corresponding to $2$; we have that all $q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $q < 2$ are in $\alpha$. Consider now $-4$ : we have that for e.g. $r=0.5$ : $-p-r=4-0.5=3.5 \notin \alpha$. Thus, according to the costruction, $p \in \beta$ as expected, because $p$ is $-4$ and $\beta$ must define $-2$.

Comment: Consider instead $-1$; we have no $r >0$ such that $-p-r=1-r$ is out of $\alpha$, because for values of $r$ greater than $1$ : $1-r < 0 < 2$ and thus is in $\alpha$, while for values of $r$ less than $1$ (but positive) $1-r < 1 < 2$ and thus again it is in $2$.